# Unity Application crash while loading files in UniTask

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

[this is an image of call stacks on the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nLf2.png)

While loading Scenes, we load files, specifically music, video, and shaders. In the meantime, Our application crashes. This process appears to be triggering an out-of-memory error. We have a dump file related to this crash.
We would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance in understanding the cause of this issue.

we have first thought what is causing this issue was async/ void which we originally used. then, switched to Unitask. but still remain unsolved.

Comment: `out-of-memory error` sounds like you are trying to load to much stuff ..?